# Exception from sub meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions id KR4Rv8gXwA2mGkpzS TypeError: Property 'check' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: meteor

I don't know the source of the error but I'm ready to give whatever the information needed

I'm getting the following errors from this morning, I tried to 'meteor update' alos but getting same error
 [image]

```
Exception from sub meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions id oYzAnzSXDaszzNcbq TypeError: Property 'check' of object #<Object> is not a function
I20150519-18:20:51.861(5.5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.publish.is_auto [as _handler] (packages/autoupdate/autoupdate_server.js:148:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:950:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at [object Object].MeteorX.Subscription._runHandler (packages/meteorhacks:unblock/lib/unblock.js:47:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at [object Object].MeteorX.Session._startSubscription (packages/meteorhacks:unblock/lib/unblock.js:35:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:582:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at [object Object].MeteorX.Session.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/meteorhacks:unblock/lib/unblock.js:9:1)
I20150519-18:20:51.862(5.5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1
```

Comment: Are you using the package [audit-arguments-checks](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/audit-argument-checks)?

Comment: @musically_ut no, I'm not using that,  looks like the error is because of kadira